# Solutions to diophantinte equation $x^4+2y^4=z^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

It is well known that the equation $x^4+y^4=z^2$ has no non-trivial solutions. The same holds also for the equation $x^4+2y^4=z^4$. What about the equation 
$x^4+2y^4=z^2$?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624105/proof-by-descent-flt.

Answer (score 2):

The classic book [Diophantine Analysis](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/20073) by R. D. Carmichael says on page 17 that the equation $x^4+2y^4=z^2$ has no non-trivial solutions. Here is the original text, slightly edited:

> 4. The equation $x^4+2y^4=z^2$ is impossible in integers $x$, $y$, $z$, all of which
>      are different from zero. 
>      *Suggestion*. This may be proved by the method of infinite descent.  Begin by writing $z$ in the form
>      $
>    z = x^2 + \frac{2py^2}{q},
>    $
>      where $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime integers, and thence show that $x^2=q^2-2p^2$,
>      $y^2=2pq$, provided that $x$, $y$, $z$ are prime each to each.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. What about the equation $x^4+3y^4=z^2$?

Comment: @Silbraz: The flow of your question seems to imply that if $x^4+dy^4=z^4$ has no solutions, then what about $x^4+dy^4=z^2$? However, for $d=3$, it seems $x^4+3y^4=z^4$ has ***no*** non-trivial solution, but $x^4+3y^4=z^2$ ***does*** have as discussed in your [other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2680710/).