# Solutions to the equation $x^4+3y^4=z^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

It was proven that the equation $x^4+2y^4=z^2$ has no non-trivial solutions in integers. What about the equation 
$x^4+3y^4=z^2$? It has a solution $x=1,y=1, z=1$. Can we find all solutions?

Comment: Set $x=y$. See what happens.

Comment: It was edited. Can we find all solutions?

Comment: $y=2x$ as well.

Comment: And $(11t/3t/122t^2)$ works.

Comment: And also $(47t/28t/2593t^2)$

Comment: Same book as for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2671343/solutions-to-diophantinte-equation-x42y4-z2?rq=1), i.e., Carmichael.

Comment: Can you please indicate the page of Carmichael's book?

Comment: It's an elliptic curve.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Not a "hyperellipctic curve" ?

Comment: @Peter: No, if $P(x) =y^2$ and $P(x)$ has degree $3$ or $4$, it is only an elliptic curve.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the equation $x^4+3y^4 = z^2$ is birationally equivalent to an *elliptic curve*, hence we can find all its solutions.

However, if an easy proof there are *infinitely* many integer solutions with $\gcd(x,y)=1$ will suffice, then given an initial solution to,

$$x^4+dy^4=z^2$$

then, *in general*, further ones can be generated as,

$$S_n=\frac{x_n}{y_n}=\frac{-x^4+dy^4}{2xyz}$$

Example: Let $d=3$, and initial $x,y,z = 1,1,2$, then,

$$S_1 = \frac11\\
S_2 = \frac12\\
S_3 = \frac{47}{28}\\
S_4 = \frac{3035713}{6824776}
$$

such that,

$$47^4+3\times28^4=2593^2$$

and so on.

Comment: Note the algorithm skips the solution $x,y,z = 11,\,3,\,122$ since "infinitely many" $\neq$ "all".